# Asus k501u doesn't boot up

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

My Windows 10 installed Asus K501U laptop doesn't boot up after my daughter shut down the laptop while windows upgrade is in progress. 
I always see bios screen (blue one). 
What is your suggestion?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who has any idea on my problem? I don't want to send my laptop to Asus RMA service as they will most probably format or replace my HDD. I don't want to lose my data.

Have a nice week.